# Cassandra data import time using shell and python driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

At a particular instance, I used `CQL Shell` to import 100k rows from a csv file using `COPY`. It took about 5.695 seconds at Avg. rate:   17559 rows/s.

If I inserted the same data using `Cassandra Python driver`, `execute_async` will take about 13 secs. so why is there such a huge difference?

I am running default `Cassandra` localhost on `Win 10 X64`. Maybe it has something to do with the number of nodes in the cluster or can benefit from using batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cqlsh uses the Cassandra Python driver and ultimately is calling execute_async, can view source:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/copyutil.py
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib

Its pretty heavily optimized at this point though. It does things like splitting up the token ranges for concurrent work, custom load balancer policies, and some lower level enhancements. Also it cythonizes the python into native code if it can.